# Validation of data from VSAM file using CICS + Cobol

Tags: cobol, cics

I have a VSAM file with customer details and customer number is one of the fields. In CICS the user has to enter a customer number. *If and only if* the customer number is present in the VSAM file the next map will be sent.

How do I validate the customer number from the VSAM file?

Comment: There just **has** to be a program at your site which is already doing this. You have colleagues to help if you don't know how to locate it. Doing it the same way as it is already done is better than coming up with a different way (not that there is really much of a different way to do this).

Comment: I agree with Bill, for just about anything you need to write on the mainframe, there will be an existing example, ask and look around, learn the basics and learn how use scan. Most mainframe programmers "collect" programs that they can use as an examples / copy from.

Answer (score 3):

CUSTOMER NO sounds as if it is a number, you should validate that it is a number.

To check if it exists in CICS, you can use the CICS READ command see [Cics Read](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/commands/dfhp4_read.html); i.e.

```
Exec CICS
    Read File(..)
    INTO(data-area) RIDFLD(data-area)
    blah blah blah ...
end exec.
```

where RIDFLD is the record-key

I would suggest finding an **Existing program** where you work (I am assuming you are not a student) and use it as an **example**. These days it is rare to write a program from scratch on the mainframe. There is nearly always an existing example you can look at copy.

Also you should show us what you **have tried !!!**

Comment: I can't think of a different way to really do it :-) I dislike things being numbers just because they have NO in the name, but it happens (a lot). I'd do the look-up first, then test for numeric only if not found, but the result is the same.